# Why is Gnuplot giving me this error?

Tags: gnuplot, gnu

I am trying to plot the following data (shortened for posting):

```
0.5 1.95958 -1.98288 0.000471732 0.00130228
0.55 2 -2 0 0
0.6 2 -2 0 0
0.65 2 -2 0 0
0.7 2 -2 0 0
0.75 1.99992 -1.99984 2.271e-07 4.25813e-08
0.8 1.99972 -1.99944 6.951e-07 1.3902e-07
0.85 1.99992 -1.99984 1.76808e-07 3.75718e-08
```

This data is stored in a data file called "ising.dat" which the data i'm trying to plot is stored column wise, and when I use the command:

```
plot "ising.dat" using 1:6 with lines title "Specific Heat"
```

I get the error:

```
warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
                                ^
     x range is invalid
```

I have tried to reset the delimiter to have it set as a whitespace but I still get the same error... I don't know what else I can do that would work. Any suggestions would be helpful (also i'm running this on a mac and even reinstalled it and get the same error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have 6 fields on your input file, just 5. Try:

```
plot "ising.dat" using 1:5 with lines title "Specific Heat"
```

(assuming column 5 is your target quantity)